# Count when object is destroyed

Tags: unity, c#

I've made a shooting game, where you shoot as many cans as possible. However, I faced a problem when counting the cans that are shot. I've tried using `void onDestroy()`, but it doesn't react when I shoot a can. Furthermore the *Text Mesh* I've set doesn't change. I've put the text mesh in the script correctly, in the editor.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You want "OnDestroy" not "onDestroy," I think (according to [the docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnDestroy.html)). The first letter should be capitalized.

Comment: OnDestroy: This function is called after all frame updates for the last frame of the object’s existence (the object might be destroyed in response to Object.Destroy or at the closure of a scene). So doing the counting in this event function might lead to bugs. I would suggest you do the counting where you detect the collision of the shot and t he can. Cheers.

Comment: When you are taking score, it might be better to increment the score in the same method where you call `Destroy(object)`. When you use the `OnDestroy` event, you have no way to remove the targets from the game without also incrementing the player's score. The usual purpose of the `OnDestroy` event is to perform any cleanups which are necessary when an object stops existing for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at [the Unity API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnDestroy.html):

> ## MonoBehaviour.OnDestroy()
>
> ### Description
>
> This function is called when the MonoBehaviour will be destroyed.
> OnDestroy will only be called on game objects that have previously been active.
>
> <sup>**[- Unity Scripting API: MonoBehaviour.OnDestroy()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnDestroy.html)**</sup>

---

You **must** call `OnDestroy()` for logic pertaining to when  the object is destroyed. `onDestroy()` is an entirely differant method, with no explicit functionality.